# GUI file is coming as NOT FOUND in the browser in the spring v5 REST application without using any xml file

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, dispatcher, spring-restcontroller

I have created a Spring 5.x REST Application for learning purpose where i am not using xml files like web.xml or spring-config xml file. In this application, there is controller and GUI file. 
My issue is, with the below code of container initialization , I am either able to access GUI page or controller from browser but not both.

**CASE-1:**
In the overriding method getServletMappings(), if we will pass the string "/", My REST controller method will be invoked properly but GUI page(index.html) is coming as "Not found".

**CASE-2:**
In the overriding method getServletMappings(), if we will pass the string "/rest", My controller method will be coming as "Not Found" and GUI page(index.html) is accessible.

I think we also uses the same kind of concept in case of web.xml file. we just write like "/rest" in servlet mapping to pass the URL containing "/rest" string to dispatcherServelet and if that URL is not containing it, will be getting used for GUI pages. But I dont have idea to implement the same thing here.

```
public class SpringMvcInitializer 
extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { SecurityConfig.class, DbConfiguration.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/rest" };
    }

}
```

Please help me on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, instead of "/" i was trying to use "/rest" which is class level requestMapping for the controller in the getServletMappings(). So that url
   without containing "rest" will not go though dispatcherServlet and serve the request for the UI pages and URL containing "/rest" will be mapped for the
   controller method. But it didn't work.
   After many hit and try i finally got the solution: What i tried is, I have created a prefix for the incoming URL. and using this prefix string in the 
   getServletMappings() method. Now if i will try to access the controller resource using this prefix string in the URL, it will work fine and in the same way
   if i will use the URL for the UI pages without without using prefix string it will also worked fine.

**-> Way to add prefix in the URL:**

add application.properties file in the resources folder with content where "/api/*" is prefix string.

```
  server.contextPath=/api/*
```

**->** Now if we are having a URL "http:localhost:8080/project_name/register_api" for the controller, then this URL will become:
         *"http://localhost:8080/project_name/api/register_api"*

**->** URL for the UI page index.html will be usual as below:
         *"http://localhost:8080/project_name/index.html"*